# Threading NSStream

Tags: ios, networking

I have a TCP connection that is open continuously for communication with an external device.  There is a lot going on in the communication pipe which causes the UI to become unresponsive at times.

I would like to put the communication on a separate thread.  I understand `detachNewThread` and how it calls a `@selector`.  My issue is that I am not sure how this would be used in conjunction with something like `NSStream`?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than manually creating a thread and managing thread safety issues, you might prefer to use Grand Central Dispatch ('GCD'). That allows you to post blocks — which are packets of code and some state — off to be executed away from the main thread and wherever the OS thinks is most appropriate. If you create a serial dispatch queue you can even be certain that if you post a new block while an old one has yet to finish, the system will wait until it finishes.

E.g.

```
// you'd want to make this an instance variable in a real program
dispatch_queue_t serialDispatchQueue = 
            dispatch_queue_create(
                       "A handy label for debugging",
                       DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

...

dispatch_async(serialDispatchQueue,
^{
    NSLog(@"all code in here occurs on the dispatch queue ...");
});

/* lots of other things here */

dispatch_async(serialDispatchQueue,
^{
    NSLog(@"... and this won't happen until after everything already dispatched");
});

...

// cleanup, for when you're done
dispatch_release(serialDispatchQueue);
```

A very quick introduction to GCD [is here](http://www.alexbrie.com/2011/11/quick-introduction-to-grand-central-dispatch-and-why-you-should-use-it/), Apple's [more thorough introduction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/BlocksGCD/) is also worth reading.

Comment: Ok, I still am a bit confused.  The GCD approach still executes a specific bit of code.  To move NSStream to the background using GCD should I allocate and init the object wrapping the NSStream inside the dispatch_async?

Comment: I think Tommy suggests that you hand the specific NSStream events (delegate callbacks) over to GCD as blocks. As Tommy writes, if you create a serial dispatch queue, GCD will make sure that a new block is not executed before the previous block has finished executing.